# Firebase app Background or killed notfication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm programming a Firebase app for sending a notification when my app has a values(number)in red. I tried to send a message when the app is running in the background or is killed, but my program doesn't work and I don't know how to call the `onMessageReceived()` method.

Station1.java

```
public class Station1 extends AppCompatActivity implements getData.ReturnValue {

private MyFirebaseMessagingService FBMessagingService = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      //widget id 
  }

        if (mpxInt < mpxIntMin || mpxInt > mpxIntMax) {
            Mpx.setText(valeurs.getMpx());//affiche la valeur mpx dans le textView
            Mpx.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#DF0101"));//red
            FBMessagingService.onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage);//?
        } else {
            Mpx.setText(valeurs.getMpx());
        }

}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    //you can get your text message here.
    String text= data.get("text");

    Intent i =new Intent(this,Station1.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new 
    NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM NOTIFICATION");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notidicationManager= (NotificationManager) 

    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notidicationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please format your code properly so it'll be easier to read. Are you trying to send the notification from the console or an app server?

Comment: i want to send a notification from the console automatically i edit my post

Comment: i'm sorry but i can't edit the code proprely he don't want color the code ...